Understanding causality errors when using `pre` and `last` in a Scade program
In Scade language referece, these is a code sample illustrate the causality error for variable y:
type T = enum {a, b, c};
node WhenBlkSample(x: T) returns (y: T last = b)
let 
  activate when y match 
  | a: y = a -> pre(y);
  | b: y = x;
  | c: -- empty 
  returns ..;
tel 

The output of the scade compiler (kcg) is as the following
*** Causality Error (ERR_400): Causality error
  at file ..., line 5, character 7
  at path whenBlkSample/_:a:y=
 the definition of shared flow y depends on flow y via the control context ;
  at file ..., line 2, character 34
  at path whenBlkSample/y/
 the definition of flow y depends on shared flow y via a control block ;

I still have trouble to understand it. Could anyone give some insight?
